# ASP.NET MVC 3 shows cached session values during page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, caching

I am working on one old ASP.NET MVC version 3 project. I am banging my head against wall for one weird issue. Issue is like in following line of code in cshtml view Session["FirmName"] is always showing old value after page refresh.

```
<label class='switchValue' id="switchClientName" title="@Convert.ToString(Session["FirmName"])">@Convert.ToString(Session["FirmName"])</label>
```

When page reloads there is code to change `Session["FirmName"]`. This issue is not reproduced in our local environment but is seen only in production. What is there which is making `Session["FirmName"]` to be cached? Is it something related with caching? Any help greatly appreciate.

Comment: are you doing a ModelState.Clear() in your controller? not having that in always does weird things to me that look like caching.  Not sure it has any effect on Session though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve caching issue, I created a parameter in querystring & passed current `DateTime` value to it.